# Facebook API - get alternative emails

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Using Facebook's API, can you get the **alternative emails** list for a user?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**No, Facebook doesn't provide Alternate Email Address with the user *object*.**

Here are the *fields* that are accessible:

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/

Comment: This is mostly because I'm getting into a lot of duplicate accounts due for people who were invited with one email address, then returned to the site and clicked 'sign-in-via-facebook' which uses the 'email' permission but their "primary email" doesn't match the email make where they were actually invited at.

Thanks for the confirmation Gorfi. I thought the whole reason I, and others, enter alternative emails is so that you can be more easily connect to friends those domains? It seems this should be added as an extended permission or an included field under the "email" permission.